# Some Questions about Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So given is: $\Phi ({ (1,1) }^{ T })={ (1,2) }^{ T }\quad \Phi ({ (4,-1) }^{ T })={ (-1,3) }^{ T }$ where as Phi denotes a Linear Transformtion $\Phi :\Re ^{ 2 }\rightarrow { \Re  }^{ 2 }$.

The exercise is to determin all Linear Transformtions.

So now to my question, normaly I would look to find the representative Matrix Ax. We do so by building the Unit Vectors as linear combination of the two input vectors, the coefftiecnts Multiplied by the Images give us now the Columns of the representative Matrix. (Is there any way to do this faster?)

How do I need to proceed after I have found the representative Matrix, since with every Basis my linear transformation is explicit defined, how does this correspond to finding all linear Transformations?.
Thanks for Help (Hope i could make my Problem clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the question is that for any input $(\alpha,\beta)$ in the domain, we need to find the output $\Phi(\alpha,\beta)$.

Note that we don't have to construct a matrix corresponding to $\Phi$.

As you suggested, start by finding the output for the two standard unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

For simplicity, I'm going to drop the transpose notation.

Note that $$(1,0) = \frac{1}{5}[ (1,1) + (4,-1)].$$

So by linearity, $$\Phi(1,0) = \frac{1}{5}\cdot[\Phi(1,1)+\Phi(4,-1)] 
= \frac{1}{5}[(1,2)+(-1,3)] = \frac{1}{5}(0,5) = (0,1).$$

In addition, $$(0,1) = \frac{1}{5}[4(1,1)-(4,-1)].$$

Consequently, $$\Phi(0,1) = \frac{1}{5}[4\Phi(1,1)-\Phi(4,-1)] = 
\frac{1}{5}[4(1,2) - (-1,3)] = (1,1) .$$

This gives us the general equation,

$$\Phi(\alpha,\beta) = \alpha\Phi(1,0) + \beta\Phi(0,1) = \alpha(0,1) + \beta(1,1).$$

Comment: Thanks! Your answer Solved my Problem